# let user manually crop image with specific size as output

Tags: javascript, html, image, thumbnails, crop

I'm trying to find some plugin on tutorial on the following:
I want that users on my website can upload an image, which will be used as thumbnail,
though the tumbnails has a specific hight/width, so the image should be cropped.

Though because those images will be images of the persons themselves, I cannot simply autocrop it. I need something that gives the user the possibility to choose which part of the image will be used. So that they can just select their head as profile image for example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't try to do image manipulation with Javascript. You need some server side stuff, like gd2 for PHP.

Comment: ic, though I was looking for some kind area selector which will be used as new image.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, [jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) is a great plugin.

Comment: jCrop has a thumbnail feature which is exactly what I need, though I cannot find any tutorial on how to save the output as a file on the server :S

Answer (score 0):

In php & [imagejpg](http://nl.php.net/imagejpeg) (uses GD) you could do:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
    $jpeg_quality = 80;

    $src = 'upload/test.jpg';
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
            $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

    imagejpeg($dst_r, 'path/to/output.jpg', $jpeg_quality);

    exit;
}
```

Instead of GD you could also use ImageMagick to do your server-side processing based on the canvas-coordinates you send back to the server.

However... you could also send the raw data from canvas.. canvas can render jpg (client-side) to, then you base64 encode it and upload it (again, but this time as the thumbnail that was created in canvas).

Hope this helps!